# PhpStorm shows Haml file like plain text (transcompilation works, but not the syntax highlighting)

Tags: haml, phpstorm, file-type

The syntax highlighting for my haml files in PhpStorm does not work, and the icon is just the icon for plain text. (It should be a red icon with an h, similar to the icon for the scss file.)

[image: wrong icon and no syntax highlighting]

The transcompilation works only if *File type* in the watcher is set to *Text files*. If I choose *HAML files*, it tells me that there are "No such files in scope".

[image: No such files in scope]

Any ideas, why PhpStorm recognizes the scss file, but not the haml file?

Comment: 1) Do you have HAML support plugin installed and enabled (probably you do). 2) Does it happens to this file only or any other `.haml` file as well (you have only one .haml file in your project -- so create another one (not copy, but create brand new, preferably outside of IDE to avoid user mistake which probably happened this time)

Comment: Created a new project with haml file, had same problem. The problem probably has something to do with "excluding files from project": http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/excluding-files-from-project.html#d308025e355

Comment: *"The problem probably has something to do with "excluding files from project""* Unlikely. **Q is:** That new project -- what file name that .haml file had -- the same or different?

Comment: **In any case:** `Settings | File Types` -- find **"Text files"** entry and look at patterns -- find and delete offending pattern (quite possible will be `background-clip.haml` or similar)

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you. There was the pattern `background-clip.haml`, and removing it also solved the problem for new files. Do you want to add an answer that I can mark as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all -- make sure that HAML support plugin is installed and enabled (whould be by default).

If plugin is good:

- `Settings | File Types`
- `Text files` entry
- Find and remove offending pattern (quite possible will be `background-clip.haml` or similar)