# Change file language in PhpStorm 10 and later

Tags: phpstorm

Apparently, PhpStorm 10 removed the *Change Language* feature (menu item and status bar control are gone and the command that shows up at *Help/ Find action* does not do anything obvious) and now it is only a global option (*Settings/ Editor/ File Types*).

Nonetheless, the IDE can still keep track of language in a per-file basis, as you can see in this screen-shot from the Project pane where all `.php` files are correctly identified as PHP except one:

[image: Project pane with incorrect language]

How do you correct now the file type of a specific file?

Comment: What "Change Language" are you talking about? There never was such feature for ordinary files. Right now it sounds like you are talking about [Scratch files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/scratches.html?search=scratch) (non-project temp files for experiments etc) which has `Change File Language` action .. and what it does it renames the file for you automatically (e.g. you have created file `scratch_1` with "PHP" as language .. and now want to change it to "CSS" .... so IDE will silently rename it from `scratch_1.php` to `scratch_1.css`

Comment: As for actual project files -- pick any of these (just adjust Settings path slightly if needed to match your version): 1) http://stackoverflow.com/a/29324565/783119 2) http://stackoverflow.com/a/30917701/783119 3) http://stackoverflow.com/a/26385217/783119 4) http://stackoverflow.com/a/22709627/783119 5) http://stackoverflow.com/a/39154141/783119 6) http://stackoverflow.com/a/21281563/783119 7) http://stackoverflow.com/a/22958945/783119

Comment: @LazyOne You might be right about scratch files (I no longer have PhpStorm/9 to check). And sorry for the dupe, it's sometimes so hard to find the exact search terms.